# Do I need to secure my API?

Tags: api, security, authorization

I'm working on an API service for my website. I have read a lot on this topic, though can't decide which the best solution would be for me.

My API is simple. Each user gets an **API key** for **each app** that connects to my site.
There are only 2 different calls atm:

- send_data
- get_data

The get_data is quiet harmless, with send_data you can end new entries to your mini app. Possible security problems could occur there, though calls are limited. None of the data is useful if it would fall in the wrong hands. Server side I am protected for sql injection etc.

The calls are something like this:
http://example.com/api/?call=send_data&data=DATAXYZ&api_key=KEY

The pro:

- It's super easy to use

The con:

- It's not secure

I read a lot of similar questions here and elsewhere and OAuth pops up as a possible answer on almost all of them. I know OAuth, and i think it's a lot of overhead for something I want to be easy to use for my users.

As explained in this article It's not always needed to use authorization:
http://blog.apigee.com/detail/do_you_need_api_keys_api_identity_vs._authorization/

Is this all true for my case too though or would you still recommend authentication with or without OAuth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send the API key as a GET parameter: it would be logged at the very least in the browser's history (and probably also in the proxy, if there's one), which isn't very secure. POST it instead.

I don't think it would be unsecure, in fact the widely used Basic Access Authentication sends the username and the password as plain text (base64 encoded), and in fact when using a form to log into any web service you are sending the password as plain text too. Of course this works on the assumption that the communications between the client and server are secure, so you probably want to use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion! No Get? That's too bad. It makes the API calls a lot more 'complex' for users that are not familiar with the system yet.

The idea is that I'll have my own apps that connect with the API, but other devs. can also make apps or scripts. So I guess there is no way of avoiding HTTPS.

Comment: Sending a GET request via plain HTTP is OK if you just want to control the approximate # of requests per user (as the article you linked points out). Things change When users can submit content. Anyway I don't think it's any harder to send a POST request than it is to send a GET request, plus it's more semantically correct when submitting data. As for HTTPS, I don't think it can be avoided if you are concerned about eavesdropping, and it doesn't take an expert to sniff an unsecured or WEP-protected WIFI ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally using similar API authentication methods in multiple commercial projects.
So far I've never had an issue with security but I use a slightly different approach.

What I do different:
a) API calls use a user-id/login plus an API key.
b) the API key is a salted md5 hash of the users password (you can add the userid and something else as salt)
That means people are less likely trying to "guess" an API key, you can also more easily see who is using your API in your logs (without looking up the API key).
And users can change their API key by changing their password, so if they think the API credentials might have been leaked then they can just change it.

Regarding GET/POST : If your users do not use the API themself (for example by including it in own tools/scripts/code) then I'd use POST as serans suggested.
But POST has several drawbacks, it's not as "easy" to use. It just requires a bit more work to be implemented.
So I'd offer GET as well as POST and just add a note about possible security issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion! I would be happy if I still could use GET. I really want an easy API that people who just started yesterday can understand.

Do you use https?
I'm not going to use salted passwords as API Keys though, that seems very unsafe. API Keys are separated. Inside my own app I salt everything. I could explain this process to users and provide code samples on how to salt and call.

Comment: I offer https but don't force it, it makes things often more complicate for developers.  
Just as you said: Things need to be simple if people should use it and a GET based API is one of the most simple things you can offer.
Using a modified password as api-key shouldn't be a real risk if your code and environment is trusted and unshared, otherwise you should of course store a separate key that's not related to the password (for example open-source etc).
You could offer your users an API logfile as additional security, so they can verify no one else uses their API.